# Entity Framework invalid column issue

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

When selecting from Entity Framework it is generating the SQL shown below. I have not mentioned the columns highlighted below anywhere in my project. Those columns are generating an invalid column exception.

Kindly help me to fix this issue.

Thanks
Iliyas

```
{SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_Key] AS [Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_Key], 
    [Extent1].[Question_Key] AS [Question_Key], 
    [Extent1].[Skill_Level_Key] AS [Skill_Level_Key], 
    [Extent1].[Skill_Code] AS [Skill_Code], 
    [Extent1].[Level_number] AS [Level_number], 
    [Extent1].[Record_Start_Date] AS [Record_Start_Date], 
    [Extent1].[Record_End_Date] AS [Record_End_Date], 
    [Extent1].[Record_Created_Date] AS [Record_Created_Date], 
    [Extent1].[Record_Modified_Date] AS [Record_Modified_Date], 
    [Extent1].[Record_Status_Key] AS [Record_Status_Key], 
    [Extent1].[Record_Modified_By] AS [Record_Modified_By], 
    [Extent1].[Record_Created_By] AS [Record_Created_By], 
    [Extent1].[Phoenix_Users_T_User_Key] AS [Phoenix_Users_T_User_Key], 
    [Extent1].[Phoenix_Users_T1_User_Key] AS [Phoenix_Users_T1_User_Key], 

***[Extent1].[Phoenix_Users_T_User_Key1] AS [Phoenix_Users_T_User_Key1], 
    [Extent1].[Phoenix_Users_T_User_Key2] AS [Phoenix_Users_T_User_Key2]***

FROM [dbo].[Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_T] AS [Extent1]
```

These are my entity classes:

```
public partial class Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_T : BaseVo<Int64>
{
    [Key]
    public int Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_Key { get; set; }
    public int Question_Key { get; set; }
    public int Skill_Level_Key { get; set; }
    public string Skill_Code { get; set; }
    public int Level_number { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Record_Start_Date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Record_End_Date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Record_Created_Date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Record_Modified_Date { get; set; }
    public int Record_Status_Key { get; set; }
    public int Record_Modified_By { get; set; }
    public int Record_Created_By { get; set; }
    public virtual Phoenix_Users_T Phoenix_Users_T { get; set; }
    public virtual Phoenix_Users_T Phoenix_Users_T1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Questions_T Questions_T { get; set; }
    public virtual Record_Status_T Record_Status_T { get; set; }
    public virtual Skill_Levels_T Skill_Levels_T { get; set; }
}

public class Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_TMap :  EntityTypeConfiguration<Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_T>
{
    public Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_TMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_Key);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_Key)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        this.Property(t => t.Skill_Code)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(64);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_T");
        this.Property(t => t.Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_Key).HasColumnName("Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_Key");
        this.Property(t => t.Question_Key).HasColumnName("Question_Key");
        this.Property(t => t.Skill_Level_Key).HasColumnName("Skill_Level_Key");
        this.Property(t => t.Skill_Code).HasColumnName("Skill_Code");
        this.Property(t => t.Level_number).HasColumnName("Level_number");
        this.Property(t => t.Record_Start_Date).HasColumnName("Record_Start_Date");
        this.Property(t => t.Record_End_Date).HasColumnName("Record_End_Date");
        this.Property(t => t.Record_Created_Date).HasColumnName("Record_Created_Date");
        this.Property(t => t.Record_Modified_Date).HasColumnName("Record_Modified_Date");
        this.Property(t => t.Record_Status_Key).HasColumnName("Record_Status_Key");
        this.Property(t => t.Record_Modified_By).HasColumnName("Record_Modified_By");
        this.Property(t => t.Record_Created_By).HasColumnName("Record_Created_By");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Phoenix_Users_T)
            .WithMany(t => t.Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_T)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.Record_Modified_By);
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Phoenix_Users_T1)
            .WithMany(t => t.Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_T1)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.Record_Created_By);
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Questions_T)
            .WithMany(t => t.Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_T)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.Question_Key);
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Record_Status_T)
            .WithMany(t => t.Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_T)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.Record_Status_Key);
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Skill_Levels_T)
            .WithMany(t => t.Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_T)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.Skill_Level_Key);

    }
}
public partial class Phoenix_Users_T : BaseVo<Int64>
{
    public Phoenix_Users_T()
    {
        this.Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_T = new List<Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_T>();
        this.Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_T1 = new List<Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_T>();
    }

    public int User_Key { get; set; }
    public string User_Id { get; set; }
    public string User_First_Name { get; set; }
    public string User_Email { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> MRALG_Map_Key { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Record_Start_Date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Record_End_Date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Record_Created_Date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Record_Modified_Date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> User_Status_Key { get; set; }
    public string User_Last_Name { get; set; }
    public string User_Type { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Last_Phoenix_Access_Date { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_T> Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_T { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_T> Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_T1 { get; set; }
}
public class Phoenix_Users_TMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Phoenix_Users_T>
{
    public Phoenix_Users_TMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.User_Key);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.User_Key)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        this.Property(t => t.User_Id)
            .HasMaxLength(64);

        this.Property(t => t.User_First_Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(512);

        this.Property(t => t.User_Email)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(128);

        this.Property(t => t.User_Last_Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(512);

        this.Property(t => t.User_Type)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(20);

        this.Property(t => t.Reason)
            .HasMaxLength(1024);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Phoenix_Users_T");
        this.Property(t => t.User_Key).HasColumnName("User_Key");
        this.Property(t => t.User_Id).HasColumnName("User_Id");
        this.Property(t => t.User_First_Name).HasColumnName("User_First_Name");
        this.Property(t => t.User_Email).HasColumnName("User_Email");
        this.Property(t => t.MRALG_Map_Key).HasColumnName("MRALG_Map_Key");
        this.Property(t => t.Record_Start_Date).HasColumnName("Record_Start_Date");
        this.Property(t => t.Record_End_Date).HasColumnName("Record_End_Date");
        this.Property(t => t.Record_Created_Date).HasColumnName("Record_Created_Date");
        this.Property(t => t.Record_Modified_Date).HasColumnName("Record_Modified_Date");
        this.Property(t => t.User_Status_Key).HasColumnName("User_Status_Key");
        this.Property(t => t.User_Last_Name).HasColumnName("User_Last_Name");
        this.Property(t => t.User_Type).HasColumnName("User_Type");
        this.Property(t => t.Last_Phoenix_Access_Date).HasColumnName("Last_Phoenix_Access_Date");
        this.Property(t => t.Reason).HasColumnName("Reason");

        // Relationships
        this.HasOptional(t => t.MRALG_Map_T2)
            .WithMany(t => t.Phoenix_Users_T2)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.MRALG_Map_Key);
        this.HasOptional(t => t.User_Status_T)
            .WithMany(t => t.Phoenix_Users_T)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.User_Status_Key);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please include your relevant models and your query. We have no way to know what is going wrong with just the generated sql.

Comment: When you see Key1, Key2 added it indicates you haven't set your foreign keys up properly so EF is adding new columns. Show your models and how you relate them.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck, i have updated the code please help me to fix it.... Thanks in advance

Comment: @SteveGreene  i have updated the code please help me to fix it.... Thanks in advance

Comment: What statement is generating that SQL? i.e. context.Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_T.ToList(); etc.

Comment: @SteveGreene the first query on the screen... it is generating 2 additional columns. why is that happening

Comment: That's generated SQL - where is the source LINQ statement? I don't see anything in your models or fluent code off the top of my head that looks wrong.

Comment: @IliyasKhatib You have 4x property that refers to `Question_Qualifying_Skills_Map_T` bound by 4 different foreign keys